# --depth=1 option with Google repo

Tags: android, git, repo

I have limited space in my VM, so I am trying to checkout the latest version of the Android source (without the repo history). I did the following:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-5.1.1_r37 --depth=1
repo sync -c -j24 -q
```

It seems that the `--depth` option is not working and the checkout is still more than 6 GB. Is the option still supported?

Comment: 6gb sounds about right.

Comment: `--depth=1` reduces the size of commit history but cannot reduce the size of checkout.

Comment: I managed to finish the downloading today. It is about 21GB. so the --depth doesn't help to reduce the size of the checkout.